# Spring Data (mongo DB) persist readable value for Boolean entity attribute

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

i am currently working in a prototypical project where we are using mongo db regex queries on a very limited data set, to perform "contains" searches to do full-text-ish searches. As we have some Boolean attributes in our Entity we would like to persist readable and thus searchable String values (additional or as an alternative to the boolean JSON representation).

Let's say my Entity looks something like this:

```
public class Foo {
  protected Boolean superPowers;
  protected Boolean evil;
  //some transitive persistence thingy
}
```

And in mongo db i want something like this

```
{
  //omitting things for brevity here
  superPowers: true,
  evil: false,
  description: "Super Hero" 
}
```

or

```
{
  //omitting things for brevity here
  superPowers: true,
  evil: true,
  description: "Villain" 
}
```

alternatively it would also be ok for now to have it like this (so the combination is not evaluated)

```
{
  //omitting things for brevity here
  superPowers: "super powers", // if "true"
  evil: "", // if false it is an empty string
}
```

Thanks for your support!

Regards,

Thorben

Answer (score 0):

You can augment the document to be written by listening to `BeforeSaveEvent` in which you will get access to the domain object *and* the document derived from that domain object.

```
@Component
class AugmentingEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Foo> {

  public void onBeforeSaveEvent(BeforeSaveEvent<Foo> event) {
    // add fields to the document as needed
  }
}
```

Find more information about this in our [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events).

Comment: works like a charm! thanks Oliver for getting back so instantly!

Comment: To get a bit more insight into this topic, this is a good read by the way: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events